# Chunked transfer encoding browser experience

Tags: perl, apache, http, encoding, http-headers

Why the output of this simple Perl script >>

```
print "Content-type: text/plain\n";
print "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\n\n";
print "11\n\n";
print "0123456789ABCDEF\n";
print "11\n\n";
print "0123456789ABCDEF\n";
print "0\n\n";
```

...works for Chrome browser and does not for IE10..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ve implemented the [chunked transfer coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) wrong: Each chunk consists of the chunk size in bytes in hexadecimal notation, followed by a CRLF sequence, followed by the chunk data:

> ```
>    chunk          = chunk-size [ chunk-extension ] CRLF
> ```

```
                    chunk-data CRLF
   chunk-size     = 1*HEX
   last-chunk     = 1*("0") [ chunk-extension ] CRLF
   chunk-data     = chunk-size(OCTET)
```

So your code should look like this:

```
print "Content-type: text/plain\r\n";
print "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n";
print "\r\n";
# first chunk
print "10\r\n";
print "0123456789ABCDEF\r\n";
# second chunk
print "10\r\n";
print "0123456789ABCDEF\r\n";
# last chunk
print "0\r\n";
print "\r\n";
```

Comment: Of course, `\n` itself can be `\r\n` on some configurations. Therefore, it may be preferable to explicitly say `\015\012` instead of `\r\n` inside networking applications.